# match color and tone of images (javascript, imagemagick whatever)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, imagemagick

Is it possible to automatically match the color/tone/contrast of multiple images (like you could do in Photoshop for example) directly on upload in a web app? The goal is to have user generated content, but to keep the experience homogeneous visually.

Comment: There are several techniques for doing this in pairs of images. 1) histogram matching, 2) brightness/contrast matching via mean and std, 3) match each image to a common set of mean and std.  I have several bash unix shell scripts that work with imagemagick. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php, http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/matchimage/index.php and http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/redist/index.php

Comment: That's an awesome collection of scripts!!! Thanks alot!